# Running statements in shell gives different output

Tags: erlang

Simple code:

```
-module(on_exit).
-export([on_exit/2, test/0]).

on_exit(Pid, Fun) ->
    spawn(fun() ->
                  Ref = erlang:monitor(process, Pid),
                  receive
                      {'DOWN', Ref, process, Pid, Why} ->
                          Fun(Why)
                  end
          end).

test() ->
    Fun1 = fun() -> receive Msg -> list_to_atom(Msg) end end,
    Pid1 = spawn(Fun1),

    Fun2 = fun(Why) -> io:format("~w died with error: ~w~n", [Pid1, Why]) end,
    _Pid2 = spawn(on_exit, on_exit, [Pid1, Fun2]),

    Pid1 ! hello.
```

In the shell:

```
1> c(on_exit).
{ok,on_exit}

2> on_exit:test().
<0.39.0> died with error: noproc
hello

3> 
=ERROR REPORT==== 9-Apr-2017::05:16:54 ===
Error in process <0.39.0> with exit value: {badarg,[{erlang,list_to_atom,[hello],[]},{on_exit,'-test/0-fun-0-',0,[{file,"on_exit.erl"},{line,14}]}]}
```

Expected Output:

```
5> Pid1 ! hello.
<0.35.0> died with error: {badarg,[{erlang,list_to_atom,[hello],[]}]}
hello

6> 
=ERROR REPORT==== 9-Apr-2017::05:15:47 ===
Error in process <0.35.0> with exit value: {badarg,[{erlang,list_to_atom,[hello],[]}]}
```

In fact, the expected output is what I see if I take each line in test() and paste it into the shell.  Why do I get the noproc (no process) error when I run the same lines inside a function?

From the [docs](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/processes.html#id87952):

> 12.8  Monitors
>
> An alternative to links are monitors. A process Pid1 can create a
>   monitor for Pid2 by calling the BIF erlang:monitor(process, Pid2). The
>   function returns a reference Ref.
>
> If Pid2 terminates with exit reason Reason, a 'DOWN' message is sent
>   to Pid1:
>
> ```
> {'DOWN', Ref, process, Pid2, Reason}
> ```
>
> If Pid2 does not exist, the 'DOWN' message is sent immediately with
>   ***Reason set to noproc***.

Comment: Do you get the expected output if you add `timer:sleep(100),` before `Pid1 ! hello.`?

Comment: @Dogbert, Yes!  That would seem to indicate that `spawn()` executes asynchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code contains a race condition -- `spawn` is asynchronous and might return before the process is spawned, and you might end up sending and crashing `Pid1` before `on_exit:on_exit/2` starts monitoring it, which causes the `erlang:monitor/2` call to immediately send a `noproc` message to the caller:

```
1> Pid = spawn(fun() -> ok end).
<0.59.0>
2> erlang:monitor(process, Pid).
#Ref<0.0.1.106>
3> flush().
Shell got {'DOWN',#Ref<0.0.1.106>,process,<0.59.0>,noproc}
ok
```

The code works fine in the shell probably because the Erlang VM executes some things slowly in the shell than when the code is compiled, but this behavior is not guaranteed. This is a classic race condition.

Erlang has a solution for this: `erlang:spawn_monitor/{1,3}`. This function is guaranteed to attach the monitor as soon as the function is spawned. You'll have to re-arrange your code a bit to use it instead of `spawn/3` + `erlang:monitor/1`.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't bother checking the definition of `monitor/2` because I was reading the erlang docs on processes--and it made no mention of it being asynchronous, which is sort of an important detail.  But, now that I check the definition: *Note!
The monitor request is an asynchronous signal. That is, it takes time before the signal reaches its destination.*  Wtf?!  Where's the event call back loop to which I can add a fun that executes monitor/2?